Как отследить значение компонента при его загрузке vue?
Есть компонент у которого есть pageData и поле minor. Возможно ли как-то при загрузке этого компонента\открытии страницы отследить что происходит со значением этого поля? Если это можно сделать в VueDevTools, то где и как?
const pageData = reactive({
  minor: applicationData.value?.fio_minor_sportsman ?? null,
    ),
  },


Да, гуглите хуки жизненного цикла компонента, выбирайте нужный и вперед!
